# Synchronous Counter to go through sequence 1,2,5,6,3,4,7,0

Tags: digital-logic, counter, synchronous

I have been working on a question which is:
Design a synchronous up-counter that goes through the sequence 1 2 5 6 3 4 7 0 and then repeats. Implement the counter using D flip-flops.

So Far I have the managed to work out the following:

[image]

Is this correct?

Would it be correct to use this truth table instead of the previous one?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: no I haven't simulated it.

Comment: Maybe try it - that way you get your answer. In answer to your question, no, it isn't right.

Comment: It's close though. Your Kanaugh maps are right, but one of your equations from one of the Karnaugh maps is wrong. I'll let you figure out which...

Comment: But for future reference, it is the job of your lecturer/teacher to mark your work, not us.

Comment: sorry I am actually preparing for an exam and came across this question.

Comment: But to test it you can actually use some simulator. There are several pretty good ones and free. And easy to use.

Comment: +1, for once, a student not directly putting a scan of the problem statement without further research, that deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If your teacher asked to design this with only D flip flop , I don't know is it possible of not, But using 3 D flip flop and a 2 half adder (or 1 full adder) , you can easily design it. if you look closely , your LSB bit ( "C" ) just flipped in every clock cycle and AB is just the value of "AB+C" bits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHeLuy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>